# Elixir change to a directory and run a shell script

Tags: elixir

In elixir code I am looking to change location to a directory and run a script there

```
File.cd!("/opt/test/", System.cmd("./bin/myscript.sh", []))
```

The second argument to File.cd! is a function and I thought the System.cmd would satisfy the requirement of being a function but the editor I am using says this statement will never work.

Is there some easier way to change to a directory, and execute a shell script?

Answer (score 3):

According to docs of [`System.cmd/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/System.html#cmd/2) there is option `:cd`. So you need to use just that:

```
System.cmd("./bin/myscript.sh", [], cd: "/opt/test/")
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
System.cmd("/opt/test/bin/myscript.sh", [])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass a function, you need to make it a lambda explicitly.

```
File.cd!("/opt/test/", fn() -> System.cmd("./bin/myscript.sh", []))
```